# Askbot: Is posible to turn a whole askbot instance to "read only"?

Tags: askbot

I need to turn a whole instance of askbot to "read only".

There is a configuration param or an easy way to do that?

**Why I need that?** I created a new instance of askbot where people will participate and put links to another askbot instance as references. I don't want people to be allowed to write in the old instance, I want them to generate content only in the new askbot instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, but a read-only mode would be a useful feature. I'm sure we'll have it at some point (I work at Askbot).

Answer (score 0):

This option has been added in the mean time. It's available in the admin settings under "Access control settings"

Look for:

```
Make site read-only [ ]
Default value: False
```